# Not getting the heatmap in the background using Matplotlib Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, heatmap

I have tried this and got the result as in the image:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["red","grey","green"])
df = pd.read_csv('t.csv', header=0)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax = ax1.twiny()
# Scatter plot of positive points, coloured blue (C0)
ax.scatter(np.argwhere(df['real'] > 0), df.loc[df['real'] > 0, 'real'], color='C2')
# Scatter plot of negative points, coloured red (C3)
ax.scatter(np.argwhere(df['real'] < 0), df.loc[df['real'] < 0, 'real'], color='C3')
# Scatter neutral values in grey (C7)
ax.scatter(np.argwhere(df['real'] == 0), df.loc[df['real'] == 0, 'real'], color='C7')

ax.set_ylim([df['real'].min(), df['real'].max()])
index = len(df.index)
ymin = df['prediction'].min()
ymax= df['prediction'].max()
ax1.imshow([np.arange(index),df['prediction']],cmap=cmap,
                        extent=(0,index-1,ymin, ymax), alpha=0.8)
plt.show()
```

Image:
[image: output]

I was expecting one output where the color is placed according to the figure. I am getting green color and no reds or greys.

I want to get the image or contours spread as the values are. How I can do that? See the following image, something similar:
[image: expected output]

Please let me know how I can achieve this. The data I used is here: [t.csv](https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/5a573831a0830172b508246cdfb7691f)
For a live version, have a look at [Tensorflow Playground](http://playground.tensorflow.org)

Comment: It looks like your extent values in `ax1.imshow()` is incorrect.

Could you try hardcoding: `ax1.imshow([np.arange(index),df['prediction']], extent=(-0.00015,0.00015,ymin, ymax))` and see if this fixes problem?

Comment: You have 1D data, but want to show an image (2D). That's not going to work, even if you fix the problem of the scaling, which causes only part of the data being shown.

Answer (score 8):

There are essentially 2 tasks required in a solution like this:

- Plot the heatmap as the background;
- Plot the scatter data;

**Output**:

[image]

**Source code**:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

###
# Plot heatmap in the background
###

# Setting up input values
x = np.arange(-6.0, 6.0, 0.1)
y = np.arange(-6.0, 6.0, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# plot heatmap colorspace in the background
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1)
im = ax.imshow(X, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('RdBu'), extent=(-6, 6, -6, 6), interpolation='bilinear')
cax = fig.add_axes([0.21, 0.95, 0.6, 0.03]) # [left, bottom, width, height]
fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax, orientation='horizontal')  # add colorbar at the top

###
# Plot data as scatter
###
# generate the points
num_samples = 150
theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, num_samples)

# generate inner points
circle_r = 2
r = circle_r * np.random.rand(num_samples)
inner_x, inner_y = r * np.cos(theta), r * np.sin(theta)

# generate outter points
circle_r = 4
r = circle_r + np.random.rand(num_samples)
outter_x, outter_y = r * np.cos(theta), r * np.sin(theta)

# plot data
ax.scatter(inner_x, inner_y, s=30, marker='o', color='royalblue', edgecolors='white', linewidths=0.8)
ax.scatter(outter_x, outter_y, s=30, marker='o', color='crimson', edgecolors='white', linewidths=0.8)
ax.set_ylim([-6,6])
ax.set_xlim([-6,6])

plt.show()
```

To keep things simple, I kept the colorbar range `(-6, 6)` to match the data range.

I'm sure this code can be changed to suit your specific needs. Good luck!

Comment: I guess this will help.. Let me try it with the samples I have.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer does not address your problem, or any of the points raised in my answer. This answer does not use your data. This is just a set of conveniently chosen points over a gradient. You already had that. The green plot in your question actually was a gradient, just not to the scale you expected and therefore appeared as a single colour. This answer does not address any of those points.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a possible solution.

A few notes and questions:

- What are the 'prediction' values in your data file? They do not seem to correlate with the values in the 'real' column.
- Why do you create a second axis? What is represented on the bottom X-axis in your plot? I removed the second axis and labelled the remaining axes (index and real).
- When you slice a pandas DataFrame, the index comes with it. You don't need to create a separate index (argwhere and arange(index) in your code). I simplified the first part of the code, where scatterplots are produced.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["red","grey","green"])
df = pd.read_csv('t.csv', header=0)
print(df)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Data limits
xmin = 0
xmax = df.shape[0]
ymin = df['real'].min()
ymax = df['real'].max()

# Scatter plots
gt0 = df.loc[df['real'] > 0, 'real']
lt0 = df.loc[df['real'] < 0, 'real']
eq0 = df.loc[df['real'] == 0, 'real']
ax.scatter(gt0.index, gt0.values, edgecolor='white', color='C2')
ax.scatter(lt0.index, lt0.values, edgecolor='white', color='C3')
ax.scatter(eq0.index, eq0.values, edgecolor='white', color='C7')
ax.set_ylim((ymin, ymax))
ax.set_xlabel('index')
ax.set_ylabel('real')

# We want 0 to be in the middle of the colourbar, 
# because gray is defined as df['real'] == 0
if abs(ymax) > abs(ymin):
    lim = abs(ymax)
else:
    lim = abs(ymin)

# Create a gradient that runs from -lim to lim in N number of steps,
# where N is the number of colour steps in the cmap.
grad = np.arange(-lim, lim, 2*lim/cmap.N)

# Arrays plotted with imshow must be 2D arrays. In this case it will be
# 1 pixel wide and N pixels tall. Set the aspect ratio to auto so that
# each pixel is stretched out to the full width of the frame.
grad = np.expand_dims(grad, axis=1)
im = ax.imshow(grad, cmap=cmap, aspect='auto', alpha=1, origin='bottom',
               extent=(xmin, xmax, -lim, lim))
fig.colorbar(im, label='real')
plt.show()
```

This gives the following result:
[image: scatterplot with gradient in background]

Comment: Wow it looks great. But you have used real values and not the prediction. May I know what will happen if you use prediction? Because that is the time when this happens and I get problem.

Comment: The real and prediction values are not correlated in any way that I can see. `plt.plot(df['real'], df['prediction'])` produces [this](https://imgur.com/a/3a3C0uk).

Comment: Also, from the example image you gave, the background does not seem to contain any additional information on top of what is visualized by the dots. It is merely a colourful guide to the eye, from what I can tell. In other words: the gradient and the dots display the same information.

Comment: Alright, give me some time. Need to check how it works in my scenario.